# SiC MOSFETS power dissipation; for heat sink sizing

Tags: mosfet, pcb, transformer, power-electronics, power-dissipation

I want to calculate the max. power dissipated for SiC Mosfet in a 6.6KW CLLLC resonant converter with full bridges on primary and secondary sides.

[image: Dual active bridge]

Let's consider the case when the input voltage is 400 VDC the output voltage will be 300 V. The MOSFETs on the secondary side will dissipate more power.

I guess we can multiply the R.M.S current by 2 SiC MOSFETs \$ Rds_{on}\$, this gives the total power losses on the single side of the converter.

Pd = \$ I_{r.m.s}^2 \times  2 . Rds_{on}  \$

1-Can you illustrate how the max power dissipation is calculated for a single SiC MOSFETs assuming max efficiency(the value to use for heat sink sizing for a single Mosfet not four MOSFETs), and how can I calculate switching losses.

MOSFETs Rdson=0.035 ohms. datasheet from [here](https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/1185/product/253/c3m0030090k.pdf)

2-The max current value on each leg; which is to be used in trace width calcualtion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: switching losses - f*V*I*(ton + toff)/2

Comment: For current value (I), using r.m.s current which is 6600/300 /sqrt(2)=15.5 Amps. plug this value in the equation above we get the switching losses for a single Mosfet on the secondary side. am I correct?

Comment: by the way, the body diode is losing power during dead time. at some instances it can be significant

Comment: The \$r_{DS(on)}\$ must always be selected at the highest temperature for worst-case dissipation calculation and it seems to be 41 mohms as a typical value. Second, it is always a problem to calculate switching losses as they involve parasitics contribution difficult to characterize and include in the equations. Furthermore, in your case, if the deadtime is well adjusted, you'll have ZVS and turn-on losses disappear. Body diode conduction time must also be accounted for the total dissipated power.

Comment: Thanks for the good hints, I ran a simulation of forward power flow mode, and the total combined losses of the primary side is 74W, do all four mosfets dissipate power equally (74/4 )?

Comment: @Verbal , Zero voltage switching is insured on the primary side; by setting proper dead time on the gate drive IC, effective Coss for the mosfets are estimated . magnetizing inductace is calculated based on these values to ensure ZVS on primary side.

Comment: @Verbal can we now estimate the losses?

Comment: To estimate losses in simulation, it is quite simple: plot the instantaneous drain current \$i_D(t)\$ and the instantaneous drain-source voltage \$v_{DS}(t)\$ of each power switch. Then, multiply both to obtain the instantaneous power \$p_D(t)=i_D(t)v_{DS}(t)\$. Finally, integrate the result precisely over one switching period to obtain \$P_D\$. The result will include all losses, conduction and switching.

Comment: what about max current rating for each mosfet leg?, I used the r.m.s value of current on the switch node (15.5 Amps ) to calculate minimum trace width, and half of that current value(7.75 amps) for each drain of high mosfet and source of low mosfet. and plug these value to trace width calculator https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html